# Parsing XML using unix terminal

Tags: xml, unix, parsing, shell, csv

Sometimes I need to quickly extract some arbitrary data from XML files to put into a CSV format. What's your best practices for doing this in the Unix terminal? I would love some code examples, so for instance how can I get the following problem solved?

Example XML input:

```html
<root>
    <myel name="Foo" />
    <myel name="Bar" />
</root>
```

My desired CSV output:

```
Foo,
Bar,
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want the name attributes of any element, here is a quick but incomplete solution.

(Your example text is in the file *example*)

> grep "name" example | cut -d"\"" -f2,2
>   | xargs -I{} echo "{},"

Answer (score 13):

[Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004/parsing-xml-using-unix-terminal#29023) is correct, but it outputs a trailing line feed.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="myel">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Just run e.g.

```
xsltproc stylesheet.xsl source.xml
```

to generate the CSV results into standard output.

Answer (score 9):

Use a command-line XSLT processor such as [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html), [saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) or [xalan](http://xalan.apache.org/) to parse the XML and generate CSV. Here's [an example](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xmldev/200404/post60210.html), which for your case is the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="myel"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="myel">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 7):

XMLStarlet is a command line toolkit to query/edit/check/transform
XML documents (for more information, see [XMLStarlet Command Line XML Toolkit](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/))

No files to write, just pipe your file to xmlstarlet and apply an xpath filter.

```
cat file.xml | xml sel -t -m 'xpathExpression' -v 'elemName' 'literal' -v 'elname' -n
```

-m expression
-v value
'' included literal
-n newline

So for your xpath the xpath expression would be //myel/@name
which would provide the two attribute values.

Very handy tool.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little ruby script that does *exactly* what your question asks (pull an attribute called 'name' out of elements called 'myel'). Should be easy to generalize

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'rexml/document'

xml = REXML::Document.new(File.open(ARGV[0].to_s))
xml.elements.each("//myel") { |el| puts "#{el.attributes['name']}," if el.attributes['name'] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test file is in `test.xml`.

```
sed -n 's/^\s*<myel\s*name="\([^"]*\)".*$/\1,/p' test.xml
```

It has its pitfalls; for example if it is not strictly given that each `myel` is on one line you have to "normalize" the XML file first (so each `myel` is on a separate line).

Comment: This looks like it got mangled over the years. `sed` does not generally support `\s`, though some modern variants do. I salvaged the code from an earlier version but perhaps review the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the original question, assuming xml file is "test.xml" that contains:

```xml
<root>
<myel name="Foo" />
<myel name="Bar" />
</root>
```

```
tr -s "\"" " " < text.xml | awk '{printf "%s,\n", $3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -s input.xml -e '//myel/concat(@name,",")'
```

Answer (score 1):

[yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) can be used for XML parsing.

It is a lightweight and portable command-line YAML processor and can also deal with XML.
The syntax is similar to [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

**Input**

```
<root>
  <myel name="Foo" />
  <myel name="Bar">
    <mysubel>stairway to heaven</mysubel>
  </myel>
</root>
```

**usage example 1**

`yq e '.root.myel.0.+name' $INPUT` (version >= 4.30: `yq e '.root.myel.0.+@name' $INPUT`)

```
Foo
```

**usage example 2**

`yq` has a nice builtin feature to make XML easily grep-able

`yq --input-format xml --output-format props $INPUT`

```
root.myel.0.+name = Foo
root.myel.1.+name = Bar
root.myel.1.mysubel = stairway to heaven
```

**usage example 3**

`yq` can also convert an XML input into JSON or YAML

`yq --input-format xml --output-format json $INPUT`

```json
{
  "root": {
    "myel": [
      {
        "+name": "Foo"
      },
      {
        "+name": "Bar",
        "mysubel": "stairway to heaven"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`yq --input-format xml $FILE` (`YAML` is the default format)

```yaml
root:
  myel:
    - +name: Foo
    - +name: Bar
      mysubel: stairway to heaven
```