# xml parsing of one value

Tags: xml, unix, terminal, xmlstarlet

I have a file that keeps appending the following xml.  What I want to get from into a variable is the percentComplete from the jobStatus. How would I get that? Not sure how to parse the xml. I tried using XMLStarlet but failed. I want to get the percentComplete in a variable that I can use in the shell.

```
<batchStatus name="" submissionTime="1/23/12 10:00:26 AM" sentBy="mike" 
timeElapsed="43 second(s)" timeRemaining="4 minute(s)" timeElapsedSeconds="43"
timeRemainingSeconds="294" percentComplete="12" resumePercentComplete="0" 
status="Processing" batchid="FD66DC21-6AA4-47FB-A3F0-7300C7BDAB8A" /batchStatus>
<jobStatus name="file.mov" submissionTime="1/23/12 10:00:26 AM" sentBy="mike"
 jobType="Compressor" priority="HighPriority" timeElapsed="43 second(s)" 
timeRemaining="4 minute(s)" timeElapsedSeconds="43" timeRemainingSeconds="294"
 percentComplete="12" resumePercentComplete="0" status="Processing: Transcoding" 
jobid="FDF1A488-51B9-4B9A-908B-FD5D95CE7E92" 
batchid="FD66DC21-6AA4-47FB-A3F0-7300C7BDAB8A" /jobStatus>
```

Comment: @shellter what do you mean by "tag" for xmlstarlet? I tried the --help of xmlstarlet and couldn't figure it out...any link to that tag would be helpful.

Comment: @user983223 What he meant was there is a tag on SO for `xmlstartlet` adding that to your question will enable experts to help you out in the best possible manner. I have added that tag for you. :)

Comment: xmlstarlet wouldn't be the best for this because it wants a full valid XML document, which means a single root tag enclosing everything. Once you start appending tags, it's no longer valid XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this -

```
var=$(awk -v FS="[ =\"]" '/^<jobStatus/,/\/jobStatus>$/{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/percentComplete/) print $(i+2)}' file | tail -n 1)
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $var
12
```

Comment: the problem is the xml file is consistently being appended with new data. So when I run what you wrote it gives me all the percent values not just the last one.

Comment: @user983223 Fixed it. Try the new solution

Answer (score 1):

See a similar post here: [Parsing XML using unix terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004/parsing-xml-using-unix-terminal)

If you are not accustomed to XML/XSLT and you don't want to learn to parse it, then you can do the quite and dirty and cut out the answer by means of a search.

The other option ... I would recommend the Xerces parser, but there are others. Check the above link, because both of these techniques are mentioned there.

Comment: thanks. I saw that post a while ago. That is where I found xmlstarlet from. I can't seem to figure out how to use it correctly. I tried --help but it is a bit confusing to me.