# Replacing a value in xml using variable with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace a value which i found using 'grep' in an xml file. Value is passed in a variable and i'm using 'sed' for this.

```
$ echo $AdmServerPort
9595
$ grep -A 8 AdmServer PoolServer.xml | grep Port
        <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
```

```
$ grep -A 8 AdmServer PoolServer.xml | grep Port | xargs sed "s/9090/$AdmServerPort/g"
sed: can't read <Argument: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Name=Port: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory>
```

Please help me find what am i doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use grep/sed to parse XML/HTML documents

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: You probably just want to pipe to `sed`, not pass arguments.  Ditch the `xargs` wrapper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing XML using unix terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004/parsing-xml-using-unix-terminal)

Comment: @TobySpeight Skipping `xargs` did help. But when i executed it with complete path of file and also `sed -i` then it failed again with error `sed: no input files`. Doesn't work even if i change directory to where files is. Am i doing something wrong again?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** As folks have mentioned in the comments, this is a **dangerous hack**. It is likely to have unintended side effects unless you are *certain* of the constraints on the input. If replacing `9090` on a line containing `Port` within 8 lines of a line containing `AdmServer` is exactly what you want to do, then something like this could work:

```
sed "/AdmServer/,+8 {/Port/s/9090/$AdmServerPort/}" PoolServer.xml
```

Use the `-i` flag if you want to modify the file in place.

Example input:

```xml
<AdmServer>
    <Argument Name="Foo" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Foo" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Foo" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Foo" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
</AdmServer>
```

Example output:

```xml
<AdmServer>
    <Argument Name="Foo" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9595"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9595"/>
    <Argument Name="Foo" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9595"/>
    <Argument Name="Foo" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9595"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9595"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Foo" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
</AdmServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

**libxml solution:**
You could pass a new `Port` attribute value as a parameter to xsltproc to use in an identity transform stylesheet:

```
xsltproc --stringparam new_port 9595 PoolServer.xsl PoolServer.xml
```

PoolServer.xsl:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- define $new_port as a parameter received from the shell -->
    <xsl:param name="new_port"/>

    <!-- match AdmServer/Argument 'Value' attributes
         whose sibling 'Name' attributes are 'Port' -->
    <xsl:template match="AdmServer/Argument/@Value[../@Name = 'Port']">
        <xsl:attribute name="Value">
            <xsl:value-of select="$new_port"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- recursively copy the rest of the xml document -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input PoolServer.xml:

```xml
<AdmServer>
    <Argument Name="Sample1" Value="1234"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Sample2" Value="1234"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
</AdmServer>
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AdmServer>
    <Argument Name="Sample1" Value="1234"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9595"/>
    <Argument Name="Sample2" Value="1234"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9595"/>
    <Argument Name="Port" Value="9595"/>
</AdmServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

[yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) can be used for XML processing.

**Input**

```xml
<AdmServer>
  <Argument Name="Sample1" Value="1234"/>
  <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
  <Argument Name="Sample2" Value="1234"/>
  <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
  <Argument Name="Port" Value="9090"/>
</AdmServer>
```

`PORT=9595 yq --input-format xml --output-format xml e '(.. | (select(type == "!!map") | select(."+Name" == "Port") | ."+Value")) |= env(PORT)' "$INPUT"`

- Note: Replace `+Value` with `+@Value` for version >= 4.30

**Output**

```xml
<AdmServer>
  <Argument Name="Sample1" Value="1234"></Argument>
  <Argument Name="Port" Value="9595"></Argument>
  <Argument Name="Sample2" Value="1234"></Argument>
  <Argument Name="Port" Value="9595"></Argument>
  <Argument Name="Port" Value="9595"></Argument>
</AdmServer>
```